# ios old primary icon shows when enter background after dynamic changed my app icon

Tags: ios, swift

After I use `UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName` to dynamically change my app icon, the old icon appears a moment before applying the change.

Here is the gif link : https://sm.ms/image/NBwOrVmedvLgMpD

I am using `Xcode 11` and I am on `iOS 13.1.2`

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. please describe your issue clearly. for reference, read [ask] It is unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: It happened to me as well. looks like it's an iOS bug.

Comment: Update your OS version and try again?